# Symfony2: Actually integrating FR3DLdapBundle with FOSUserBundle is problematic

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, fr3dldapbundle

Has anybody actually integrated the two?  I'm working on doing so now and I don't get how to get past the issues I'm having.

First, my versions:

- Symfony 2.0.15
- FOSUserBundle 1.2.0
- FR3DLdapBundle 1.5.x

What is *not* a problem at the moment is getting the ldap bundle to contact my ldap server and authenticate a user.  That works fine.

The problem is when it comes time to persist the user.  Here's what my user Entity looks like

```
<?php

namespace JWT\EufonyBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FR3D\LdapBundle\Model\LdapUserInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;

/**
 * JWT\EufonyBundle\Entity\User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="JWT\EufonyBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 */
class User extends BaseUser implements LdapUserInterface
{
  /**
   * Ldap Object Distinguished Name
   * @var string $dn
   */
  protected $dn;

  /**
   * @var integer $id
   *
   * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
   */
  protected $id;

  /**
   * Get id
   *
   * @return integer
   */
  public function getId()
  {
      return $this->id;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  public function setDn($dn)
  {
    $this->dn = $dn;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  public function getDn()
  {
    return $this->dn;
  }
}
```

This is what the resulting MySQL table looks like

```
mysql> describe user;
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                 | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| username              | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| username_canonical    | varchar(255) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| email                 | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email_canonical       | varchar(255) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| enabled               | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| salt                  | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| password              | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_login            | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| locked                | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| expired               | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| expires_at            | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| confirmation_token    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| password_requested_at | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| roles                 | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| credentials_expired   | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| credentials_expire_at | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The problem comes from all the columns inherited from `FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User` - specifically all the NOT NULL columns for which I'll never have values when a user authenticates with LDAP.

So what's the solution here? I can't "fake" values for columns like `user.salt` or `user.password`.

I checked the class hierarchy from `FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User` on up and the requirement for columns like `password` are in `FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface` (hierarchy below)

```
FR3D\LdapBundle\Model\LdapUserInterface <------------------------+
                                                                 |
Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface               |
  ^                                                              |
  +- Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface  |
       ^                                                         |
       +- FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface <---+               |
                                                 |               |
FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface <-------------+               |
                                                 |               |
                                      implements |               |
FOS\UserBundle\Model\User -----------------------+               |
  ^                                                              |
  +- FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User                                  |
       ^                                              implements |
       +- JWT\EufonyBundle\Entity\User --------------------------+
```

This tells me that I actually can't implement LDAP authentication for user's persisted by something that extends `FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User`, which feels like the same thing as saying "doesn't integrate with FOSUserBundle at all" despite the fact that this seems to be the whole purpose of **FR3DLdapBundle**.

And if my user class *doesn't* extends `FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User`, then I lose all the role/group goodies that **FOSUserBundle** provides out of the box.

Did I miss something in the documentation? I don't get how to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what is your problem. If you set a password and storage it in the DB then the authentication will be against the DB instead of Ldap.

You should have the following providers under the "chain provider" key:

providers: [fos_userbundle, fr3d_ldapbundle]

The order of the providers matters, you can play omitting some of their but NEVER fr3d_ldapbundle can go before fos_userbundle

(https://github.com/Maks3w/FR3DLdapBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#6-enable-fosuserbundle-as-user-provider)

If you have some special need to fill some user attribute when the user is created then you can follow this cookbook and setup your own values.

https://github.com/Maks3w/FR3DLdapBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/cookbook/override_ldap-manager.md

Regards

Comment: i know this is an old post but i want to get a better understanding when you say "If you set a password and storage it in the DB then the authentication will be against the DB instead of Ldap." Is it possible to store a user in the DB but still authenticate against LDAP? (That's what I want to do)

Comment: Yes, just don't fill the providers array and keep fr3d_ldap in your firewall

Comment: your info helped. I also had to spend more time getting ldap settings right in config.yml and now I can log in! Any pointers on why the second login from same user causes the system to try to save the user a second time and therefore fails?

Comment: I've figured it all out now. Thanks for your help!